# How to recover the customer password in Prestashop?

Tags: passwords, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem when I want to recover the password of the client.

These would be the steps for a password recovery to the user

**1. The user selects the link "Have you lost your password?"
2. In a pop-up the user writes and sends his email
3. The user receives a link to reset the password**

Here is the problem, the generated link does not perform any action, it is supposed to return an e-mail with the new password.

I do not know if it is the Link generation, its structure is as follows

**StoreName/index.php?controller=password&token=tokenNumber&id_customer=CustomerNumber**

When running, it redirects to the admin page.

**UPDATE
Or maybe in the e-mail send the password generated.**

I await your help
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must active DEBUG MODE an look for some error or notification in developer console. Also deactivate Friendly URL to avoid an accidental redirection in htaccess.

Anyway, you can reset your customer password in backoffice so he can log in and change it then.

Good luck.

Comment: The DEBUG MODE is activated and the friendly URL is deactivated. Yes I know but I need the client to recover his password. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the logic you are using to create the link is not right. You can use the following function to create URL of any front controller:

getModuleLink

The third parameter in this function can be used to add get parameters to the URL.